# Sharing laptop's internet connection to phone via USB

Tags: usb, internet, tethering

I want to share my laptop's internet to my Android phone. I have done USB tethering and don't know how to proceed further.
I now have two wired connections. I use *Wired connection 1* for Internet on my laptop and my OS is Ubuntu 17.04.

[image: Network Connections]

Creating an hotspot is not an option for me. I specifically want to use USB tethering.

Comment: USB tethering is usually the other way around, from phone to PC.

Comment: So it can't be done? https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1004745/